# Bash Script Example Needed - Locate and RM

Tags: bash

I am looking for a BASH example of locate and rm -rf

I am thinking I assign the locate results to an array, then loop that array and rm -rf

Is this what you would do?

Thank you!

Jeff

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do with this? Combining the unfiltered output of a program with `rm -rf` is very dangerous. I'd put together a `find` based answer that narrows the risk factor a bit, but I'd need more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really wanted to use locate and rm you could use something like the following:

```
for i in `locate item`; do rm -r -f $i; done
```

Be very careful with this though, because of the matching that is done with locate. If you are too general in what you type, you can delete a lot more than you originally wanted to.

You can at least get a list of the results by changing the command to:

```
for i in `locate item`; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: maybe replace rm -f with rm -i

Comment: The `$i` in the `rm` command should be `"$i"` to make sure that it doesn't try to rm each word individually if you have a filename with a space in it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is done with find and rm, something like:

`find . -name "foo" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Preferably with a path prefix on `{}`. This narrows the scope of the rm -Rf if it goes out of control due to user error.

Comment: Since rm can delete multiple files at once you can change `\;` to `+` as `-exec rm -rf {} +` and rather than running rm on one file at a time, it will run rm once with all of the files.

Comment: @DerfK Risks an overflow of input args. That said, my suggestion is incompatible with `-execdir`, which is the preferred way of doing things. Combining `rm` with any sort of automation is just nasty business.